# Request APIS for Android Video Calling feature

Tags: android

I want to place an video calling feature in android application. So is there any free APIS are available or not. Please provide some valid APIS.

Comment: refer this http://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-videochat-android

Answer (score 2):

**use cross platform WebRTC Video Calling SDKs.**

Video Calling code sample android along with associated documentation and API of quickbox is deprecated. instead use

http://quickblox.com/developers/VideoChat#SDK_.26_code_samples

*"Video chat solution using the open-source technology WebRTC. It is intended for the organisation of streaming media data between browsers or other supporting it applications for peer-to-peer technology without any additional plugins."*